# ffmpeg nvidia hwaccel yuv444p raw frame output

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, nvidia

1. I use ffmpeg to do frame decimation, millions of video
2. I have to  use nvidia gpu card (tesla P4) to optimize performance
3. my ffmpeg command is

   ```
   ffmpeg   -hwaccel cuvid  -c:v h264_cuvid -i ./a.mp4  -c:v nvenc -vf "scale_npp=format=yuv444p"  -r 1  ./\%08d.raw
   ```
4. but the output data format is weird, I don't know what the format is and how to decode it

I want to know how to decode these data or how to output ream rawdata, can anybody help me?

Log:

```
built with gcc 8.2.0 (GCC)  
configuration: --cc=/opt/compiler/gcc-8.2/bin/gcc --disable-x86asm --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-debug=3 --disable-optimizations --disable-stripping --extra-cflags='-I/home/work/cuda-10.0/include -g3' --extra-ldflags=-L/home/work/cuda-10.0/lib64 --prefix=/home/work/ffmpeg  
 libavutil      56. 36.101 / 56. 36.101  
 libavcodec     58. 65.100 / 58. 65.10  
 libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101  
 libavdevice    58.  9.101 / 58.  9.101  
 libavfilter     7. 69.101 /  7. 69.101  
 libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100  
 libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100  
 libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100  
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './a.mp4':  
 Metadata:  
   major_brand     : isom  
   minor_version   : 512  
   compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41  
   encoder         : Lavf57.71.100  
 Duration: 00:50:41.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 862 kb/s  
   Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360  >[SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 825 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)   
   Metadata: 
     handler_name    : VideoHandler 
   Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo,  fltp, 29 kb/s (default)
   Metadata: 
     handler_name    : SoundHandler 
Stream mapping: 
 Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (h264_cuvid) -> h264 (nvenc)) 
 Stream #0:1 -> #1:0 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native)) 
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help  
Output #1, wav, to './audio.wav':  
 Metadata:  
   major_brand     : isom  
   minor_version   : 512  
   compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41  
   ISFT            : Lavf58.35.101  
   Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s (default)  
   Metadata:  
     handler_name    : SoundHandler  
     encoder         : Lavc58.65.100 pcm_s16le  
[nvenc @ 0x44bbc40] This encoder is deprecated, use 'h264_nvenc' instead
Output #0, image2, to './%08d.raw':  
 Metadata:  
   major_brand     : isom  
   minor_version   : 512  
   compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41  
   encoder         : Lavf58.35.101  
   Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (nvenc) (High 4:4:4 Predictive), cuda, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 2000 kb/s, 1 fps, 1 tbn, 1 tbc (default)  
   Metadata:  
     handler_name    : VideoHandler  
     encoder         : Lavc58.65.100 nvenc  
   Side data:  
     cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/2000000 buffer size: 4000000 vbv_delay: N/A
frame= 3043 fps= 52 q=4.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:50:43.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=72984 speed=52.3x 
video:245435kB audio:6250kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: logs,plz click this link, thanks:https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXx4c.png

Comment: sorry for that, text log copied, thanks

Comment: How are you trying to decode it?

Comment: I need to get 1 frame per sec, so I try to decode it。I use ffmpeg and nvidia hardware to accelerate it

Comment: What are you using to try to decode the output from the ffmpeg command in your question?

Comment: I use opencv, cv::Mat mat =  cv::imdecode(buf, iscolor);

Comment: Seems like a question about OpenCV to me, but I don't know anything about that.

Comment: do you how to decode this type of data my ffmpeg output?